# What is the difference between transfer and redirect in SIP

Tags: sip

Is there any difference between the two call scenarios involving a SIP session?
1) Call is transfered.
2) Call is re-directed.

Answer (score 10):

In a transfer a SIP User Agent has actually established a dialog with the callee, and then initiates setting up a new dialog between the callee and another UA.

A redirect is when a UA doesn't answer the call, but simply informs the callee to resend the INVITE to another SIP URI.

In particular, a transfer will involve `REFER` and `NOTIFY` messages, meaning that the UAs involved must support the `refer` event package. This package is defined [outside](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3515) the core SIP RFCs, where redirection is covered by the main/central [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261).

Comment: Yupp. In layman terms, you hear the phone ringing and redirect (e.g. to voicemail) instead of picking up. Or during the conversation you realize the caller dialed the wrong number and transfer him to the right department.

Comment: Oh, and B2BUA-s can fake transfers with reinvites or by splicing the media stream.

Comment: Note that transfer can be implemented with the core RFC3261 message set via re-INVITE requests.

Comment: @yotommy How? A re-INVITE can't change the dialog to include the transfer target. You can do whatever you like to the media plane, sure, redirecting the media streams to an arbitrary target. That's not a transfer in the signalling sense of the word. All the REFER actually does is supply the callee with a URI to contact, with some call flow to do blind/attended/whatever transfer. But that's a _whole new call_, which a re-INVITE does not do.